# Understanding the behaviour of QDoubleValidator range

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qlineedit, qvalidator

The specification of the options 'top' and 'bottom' seems to have a strange behavior. The following [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54741145/i-use-qdoublevalidator-in-my-pyqt5-program-but-it-doesnt-seem-to-work) gave some useful insights, but does not cure everything.

With the code :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

input = QLineEdit()
input.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(0.00,10.00,5,notation=QDoubleValidator.StandardNotation))

input.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The input box accepts any number below 100, but I would expect only numbers below 10 ... For example, 99.55656 is accepted just fine...

What do I miss ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the line-edit does not *literally* accept the value `99.55656`. This can be confirmed by calling its [hasAcceptableInput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#acceptableInput-prop) method, which returns `False`.

The validator is *allowing* the value to be entered, because doing so produces a valid Intermediate state. According to [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#validate), this can happen "if it is likely that a little more editing will make the input acceptable". So in the specific case of `99.55656`, deleting a `9` would produce a valid Acceptable state. This would seem to imply that "a little more editing" should be taken to mean *adding or removing a **single** character* (where the notation is `StandardNotation`).